# Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (primary DNS server)

Tags: windows-7, networking

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium and am connecting to the Internet through Homeplug.

When I connect and enable the LAN the status shows that I'm connected (the IPv4 shows connected), but after like 20 seconds it changes to No Internet connection. Even when it says I'm connected I can't connect to the Internet. My browser (Firefox) shows Server Not Found.

When I run the troubleshooter it says "Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (primary DNS server)."

What could be the problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The reset command is available in the IP context of the NetShell utility. Follow these steps to use the reset command to reset TCP/IP manually:

1. Open a command prompt by clicking Start, typing `cmd`, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and clicking `Yes` on the UAC prompt
2. Type the following command in: `netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt`
3. Reboot the computer

I tried this on my computer and it seems to work OK for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "problem solver" (n&s center -> nic: dblclick -> diagnose) to automatically scan for errors and fix the problem. Failing that, set the DNS server manually.

If your home-router fails to acquire a working DNS server from your ISP, try using a free service such as Opendns: 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220

[image: dns]